# Game Theory - 2 Players choose between 0 and 1, if sum exceeds 1, utility for both is 0

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Two players must choose a number simultaneously between 0 and 1. If x+y≤1 they both get utility equal to the numbers that they have chosen. Otherwise both get 0 utility.

I think that the best response functions are:

Player 1: x=1-y

Player 2: y=1-x

If I substitute I get that x=x and y=y. My guess is that both players choose 1 but I don't know how to prove it.

How do I find the Nash equilibria and expected payoff?

Comment: So we have a game with infinitely many strategies and 2 players. Have you looked to see if your game is similar to any games people study? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_games_in_game_theory

Comment: In this particular game you have a set of infinite Nash Equilibrium, i.e. all cases where the sum of both numbers is equal to 1. If you are interested take a look on Bargaining Solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit more complicated, best responses are not unique if the other player plays $1$. In that case, everything gives a payoff of $0$.But for $x\in(0,1)$ you are fine. So
let $x\in (0,1)$ and look at the pair of actions $(x,1-x)$. Is $x$ a best response to $1-x$? Is $1-x$ a best response to $x$?Then you know whether $(x,1-x)$ is a Nash equilibrium. Are there other best responses?

Coming to the boundary cases, we know that for $x\in (0,1)$, the best response is $1-x\in(0,1)$, so there is no Nash equilibrium in which only one player plays $1$. But $(1,1)$ is indeed a Nash equilibrium; no player can avoid getting a payoff of $0$ by unilaterally taking a different action.

Characterizing Nash equilibria in general mixed strategies is a different, much harder, problem.

Comment: But isn't the number chosen by each player strictly between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: That is not how I read the question.

Comment: can you please help me with this problems, particularly part (d) - (f)? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564978/n-firm-cournot-model-in-an-infinitely-repeated-game