# n-firm Cournot model in an infinitely repeated game

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Given $n$ firms ($n\geq 3$). Assume $x_i\in R^{+}$. The market price is $1-\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$ if $1-\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\geq 0$, and $0$ otherwise. Each firm has a constant marginal cost of $c<1$.

The payoff function is $\pi_{i}(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n) = q_i(\text{max} \left\{1-\sum_{j=1}^{n} q_j, 0\right\} - c)$.

(a) Let $q^m$ be symmetric quantity by each firm that maximizes the joint profits. Compute $q^m$ and the corresponding symmetric profit for each firm.

(b) Compute the **min-max** payoff for firm $i$.

Now, assume that this game is repeated infinitely many times. Each firm discounts each period payoffs by $\delta \in (0,1)$. Assume each firm chooses the same quantity as each competitors after each history. Given a symmetric $q\in R^{+}$, define

$$u(q) = q(\max\left\{1-nq,0\right\} - c).$$

Also, given $u^d(q) = max_{s_i\in R^{+}}\ \pi_i(s_i,q,\ldots, q)$ is the stage-game deviation payoff by a single firm.

(c) Find **any** q so that $u(q) = u^d(q)$. Graph the two functions $u(q)$ and $u^d(q)$ (label $q^c$ and $q^m$ on the figure).

(d) Assume each firm has a **collusive** output $q^m$ in each stage of the game, and we consider a SPNE of this infinitely repeated game. Find the minimum $\delta$ in which such outcome is supported as an SPNE in an infinitely repeated game. What is the trigger strategy to support this outcome as a SPNE?

Given an alternative SPNE, where in the first period all players choose some symmetric quantity $q^S\in R^+$. In any period thereafter, each player chooses some $q^C\in R^+$. Any deviation from this prescribed choices in any period of the game causes the players to revert to the first period play in the subsequent period, starting with $q^S$ and revert to $q^C$ again until another deviation occurs (aka. carrot-and-stick strategy).

(e) Given a subgame starting at time $t$, in which the carrot-and-stick strategy prescribes playing $q^C$ in period $t$. Prove that $u^d(q^C)\leq (1+\delta)u(q^C) - \delta u(q^S)$

(f) Same assumption as in part (e), but assume carrot-and-stick strategy prescribes playing $q^S$. Prove that $u^d(q^S)\leq (1-\delta)u(q^S) + \delta u(q^C)$

(g) Can a firm be held to its min-max payoff by the stick punishment? If that is the case, what is the corresponding stick quantity $\underline{q}$?

(h)If $q^m$ is a carror and $\underline{q}$ is a stick, find the lower bound of the discount factor $\delta$ above with the carrot-and-stick strategy.

**My attempt**

(a) Due to symmetry at equilibrium and firms have constant cost, we need to find $q^m = q_1 = \ldots = q_n$ is the solution to the optimization problem: $\max_{q_1,\ldots, q_n}  (1-\sum_{i=1}^{n} q_i)(q_1+\ldots + q_n) - c(q_1 + \ldots + q_n) = \max_{q_1,\ldots, q_n} (1-nq^m)nq^m - cnq^m$.

Taking the first-order derivative w.r.t. $q^m$ and set it equal to $0$ to solve for $q^m$, we obtain $q^m = \fbox{$(1-c)/2n$}$

Then the symmetric profit for each firm $i$ is $\pi_i = [1- (1-c)/2](1-c)/2 -c(1-c)/2 =$ $\fbox{$\frac{(1-c)^2}{4}$}$

(b) We start from the definition of min-max payoff for firm i: $v_i = \min_{\sigma_{-i}} [\max_{q_i} \pi_i(q_i, \sigma_{-i})]$. From the definition of $\pi_i$, we get:

$\max_{q_i} \pi_i(q_i, \sigma_{-i}) = \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  \frac{1-c}{n+1}[\frac{n+c}{n+1} - \sum_{j\neq i}^{n} q_i - c],\ \text{if}\ (n+c)/(n+1) > \sum_{j\neq i}^{n} q_j\\
                  -c(1-c)/(n+1), \text{otherwise}
                \end{array}
                 \right.$

Thus, $v_i = \min_{q_1,q_2,\ldots, q_{i-1}, q_{i+1}\ldots, q_n} \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  \frac{1-c}{n+1}[\frac{n+c}{n+1} - \sum_{j\neq i}^{n} q_i - c],\ \text{if}\ (n+c)/(n+1) > \sum_{j\neq i}^{n} q_j\\
                  -c(1-c)/(n+1), \text{otherwise}
                \end{array}
                 \right.$

Since the first case is always greater than the second for all $q_j\neq q_i$, and the minimum of the first case, in the sense that $\sum_{j\neq i}^{n} q_j\rightarrow (n+c)/(n+1)$, is the same as that of the second case, we conclude that $\fbox{$v_i = -c(1-c)/(n+1)$}$

(c) First, $\pi_i(s_i, q, \ldots, q) = \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  s_i(1-(n-1)q-s_i-c)\ \text{if}\ s_i\leq 1-(n-1)q\\
                  -cs_i < 0\ \text{otherwise}
                \end{array}
                 \right.$

In the first case, by taking the first-order derivative w.r.t $s_i$ and set it equal to $0$ to solve for $s_i$, we obtain $s_i  = \frac{1-(n-1)q-c}{2}$. Thus, for $s_i\leq 1-(n-1)q, max_{s_i\in R^{+}}\ \pi_i(s_i,q,\ldots, q) = \frac{(1-(n-1)q\ -\ c)^2}{4}$. For $s_i\geq 1-(n-1)q$, $\pi_i (s_i,q,\ldots, q) = -cs_i$, which is a strictly decreasing function, so $\max \pi_i (s_i,q,\ldots, q) = -c(1-(n-1)q)$ over this interval.

Finally, it is easy to see that $(1-(n-1)q-c)^2/4> -c(1-(n-1)q)$, so $\max_{s_i\in R^+} \pi_i (s_i,q,\ldots, q) =  \fbox{$\frac{(1-(n-1)q\ -\ c)^2}{4}$}$. Now, since $u(q) = \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  q(1-nq-c)\ \text{if}\ 1/n > q\\
                  -qc < 0\text{otherwise}
                \end{array}
                 \right.$,

we need to find $q$ that satisfies $(1-(n-1)q-c)^2/4 = q(1-nq-c). After some algebraic manipulations, we are left with

$$q^2(n+1)^2 + (1-c)^2 - 2q(1-c)(1+n) = 0$$
$$\iff [q(n+1)-(1-c)]^2 = 0$$
$$\iff q = (1-c)/(n+1) > 0$$

I am not sure what is $q^c$, so I have no idea how to plot this point. But $q^m$ is just the same as in part (a), and the plot of $u(q)$ is comprised of two parts: one is a parabola with maximum at $(1/n, -qc)$ and the second part is a straight line with slope is $-c$, from $q=0$ to $q=1/n$.

**My question.** Is my solution to parts (a) - (c) above correct?

For (e) and (f), I spent so many hours trying to solve it using the definition of $u^d$ and $u$ derived in part (c), but I am still unsuccessful. I think the reason is because I cannot derive somehow the relationship between $q^C$ and $q^S$, although $(1+\delta)u(q^C) - \delta u(q^S)$ has $4$ parts corresponding to whether $q^S, q^C > 1/n$ or not. Finally, for (d), (g) and (h) I am completely stuck. Can someone please help me with any of these five remaining parts?

Comment: Nobody is willing to help me with (some) parts of this problem??

Comment: Really long questions have an uphill road to get attention. People think "I don't have time for this" and move on. Remember, these are volunteers. If you can isolate the parts (maybe ask about a-c in one question, then later parts in follow-up questions, and include no more than the minimum for each), you will probably have better luck. This isn't anything I've studied, so I can't help either.